# iPhone Quartz Demo, rerender PDF

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, pdf, quartz-graphics

How should I modify the QuartzDemo that comes with the iPhone so that it re-renders the PDF view like UIWebView does when you zoom in?

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer from Apple, sharing it here for completeness:

> Apple doesn't have any sample code
>   that demonstrates how to do this at
>   the moment, but Bill Dudney (who is
>   now an evangelist at Apple) has a
>   great blog post about using the
>   CATiledLayer on the iPhone to draw
>   PDFs.  I would suggest taking a look
>   at his two posts on the CATiledLayer
>   class
>   http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/tiledlayer_on_the_iphone
>   and
>   http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/catiledlayer_example.

Cheers

Nik